# regular expression xth, yth, zth char in space aligned text file

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Problem: space aligned file (first row of numbers represents the columns).

How to select spaces using regex?

```
1       2    3 4                  5
_______________________________________________________________
a09z    a09z 0 a09z a09z a09z     a09z a09z a09z a09z a09z a09z
a09z    a09z 0 a09z a09z a09z     a09z a09z a09z a09z a09z a09z
a09z    a09z 0 a09z a09z a09z     a09z a09z a09z a09z a09z a09z
a09z    a09z 0 a09z a09z a09z     a09z a09z a09z a09z a09z a09z
```

Goal: pass the regular expression to `pandas.read_csv(sep=r"")`

Comment: Do you control the creation of this file? If so, I would suggest you to fix this issue while writing the file.

Comment: I don't control the creation of the file. Otherwise this would not be an issue.

Answer (score -1):

`(?<=^.{4})\s+|(?<=^.{12})\s+|(?<=^.{14})\s+|(?<=^.{29})\s+`

match all spaces after 4 initial chars | match all spaces after 12 initial chars | ...

https://regex101.com/r/oQp7BM/2/

Comment: ideas on how to do differently?